# windows has trouble connecting to wireless at start

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My laptop has trouble connecting to any wireless network after I start it up. In general it fails to connect automatically. I them have to try several times manually by clicking on the wifi icon and choosing the available network. It doesn't matter if it's at home or when I'm with my family, so it's not my router's problem. The first few minutes I have to repeatedly try manually connecting to my wifi. After a while and several attempts it finally connects and I can internet problem free. It never fails. I never lose connection. The next time I start up my laptop, automatic connection fails again and I have to do several attempts to connect manually. Until it either connects by itself or when my manual attempt is succesful. Then, when finally connected, everything works fine again. So I assume my network card is ok, otherwise it would also fail or at least it would disconnect every now and then when that was broken.

So my question, why does this first connecting fails often for my laptop? What can make manual attempts to connect fail the first few minutes, but once connected continue to work fine? What could I check? My other netbook, apple and iphone all connect immediately by themselves once they are turned on. It's just my laptop on which automatic connection often fails. And not just at home, but on every other location where I want to connect to wifi. I have to do several attempts manually until it finally connects.

Anyone got some suggestions where to look? Or knows what could cause this initial connection to fail?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing or forgetting the network that you're trying to connect to automatically. Restarting your computer, and then re-entering the credentials. I've had this problem on my laptop before and forgetting and re-entering the credentials for that wifi network seemed to do it for me. Now this might not work for you as well. It might be a design flaw of the laptop you're using or some kind of failing software.

Trying doing this:

1. Start the Command Prompt as administrator and type the following command: netsh wlan show profiles.
2. It will display all the wireless network profiles stored by Windows 8.1. The list can be long if you used your laptop or tablet for more than a couple of weeks.
3. Identify the name of the wireless network profile you want removed, then type the following command to remove it: netsh wlan delete profile name="profile name".

Also, if that doesn't work and you're feeling extreme you can always delete all wifi networks by using the command:

netsh wlan delete profile name=* i=*.

[reference for commands](http://www.7tutorials.com/how-delete-forget-wireless-network-profiles-windows-81)

Comment: I've already tried that once. The thing is, it's not only happening with my own network. When I'm trying to connect to a wifi while on the road (for example a train or bus which offers free wifi), my iphone's hotspot or when I'm with my family, it does the same thing. The first few attempts have to be manual, until it finally connects and works problem free. Already deleted all profiles once and set them up again. But that didn't work. Once it connects everything's ok. It just these few first manual attempts that don't work. Also updated the Broadcom 802.11n driver.

Comment: Maybe try downgrading the driver? did you change or reinstall windows recently or do any OS-level changes?